# Pyspark dataframe split and pad delimited column value into Array of N index

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

There is a pyspark source dataframe having a column named X. The column X consists of '-' delimited values. There can be any number of delimited values in that particular column.
Example of source dataframe given below:

| X |
| --- |
| A123-B345-C44656-D4423-E3445-F5667 |
| X123-Y345 |
| Z123-N345-T44656-M4423 |
| X123 |

Now, need to split this column with delimiter and pull exactly N=4 seperate delimited values. If there are more than 4 delimited values, then we need first 4 delimited values and discard the rest. If there are less than 4 delimited values, then we need to pick the existing ones and pad the rest with empty character "".

Resulting output should be like below:

| X | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123-B345-C44656-D4423-E3445-F5667 | A123 | B345 | C44656 | D4423 |
| X123-Y345 | A123 | Y345 |  |  |
| Z123-N345-T44656-M4423 | Z123 | N345 | T44656 | M4423 |
| X123 | X123 |  |  |  |

Have easily accomplished this in python as per below code, but thinking of pyspark approach to do this:

```
    def pad_infinite(siterable, padding=None):
        return chain(iterable, repeat(padding))

    def pad(iterable, size, padding=None):
        return islice(pad_infinite(iterable, padding), size)
    
    colA, colB, colC, colD= list(pad(X.split('-'), 4, ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) the string into an array, separate the elements of the array [into columns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr.html) and then [fill](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fill.html) the `null` values with an empty string:

```python
df = ...
df.withColumn("arr", F.split("X", "-")) \
    .selectExpr("X", "arr[0] as Col1", "arr[1] as Col2", "arr[2] as Col3", "arr[3] as Col4") \
    .na.fill("") \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------------+----+----+------+-----+
|X                                 |Col1|Col2|Col3  |Col4 |
+----------------------------------+----+----+------+-----+
|A123-B345-C44656-D4423-E3445-F5667|A123|B345|C44656|D4423|
|X123-Y345                         |X123|Y345|      |     |
|Z123-N345-T44656-M4423            |Z123|N345|T44656|M4423|
|X123                              |X123|    |      |     |
+----------------------------------+----+----+------+-----+
```

Comment: Split is not happening as expected with this and also it is truncating my rest dataframe columns once this runs. No impact from any above step, i tried with sample dataframe, but same complete df truncation is seen.

Comment: @AmitSingh what result do you see from `spilt`? The colum `arr` should be a string array. Do you get this array?  Dropping the remaining columns is expected. This happens in the `selectExpr` statement. You can either add all other required columns to the list of columns or you can try `selectExpr("*", "arr[0]", ...)`

Comment: apologies! Split is returning the expected array. Also selectExpr needed a * character for keeping all other columns intact as you said. Thanks a ton for your help, this is an approved and expected Pyspark answer. Marking it approved.